# retrieving video and images from given link using php

Tags: php

hello i'm building website in which i need the functionality of retriving video ( if video), images, descirption from different links, like different video websites or if general website link get thumbnail and descirption.

is there any php class exist ? for this taks Please help me suggest better solution Thanks in advance...

oh yeah example is just like facebook link tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you more than likely referring to video sites such as Youtube and Vimeo.

Both sites have an API Features that you can use to get your video information:

- Vimeo

  - http://vimeo.com/api
- Youtube

  - http://www.youtube.com/dev
  - http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html
  - http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html

For a extensive frameowrk in youtube api requests you can use Zend Data: http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata

for a Vimeo PHP Library use https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib

Most other professional sites will have some sort of API out there, and there would more than likely be libraries for them.

---

> Is there any native classes that interact with all these websites ?

Short answer is no, All there API's are different, therefore no single class can interact with all the websites successfully.

What you need to do is create a Driver based package to handle this.

You base class would look something like so:

```
class VideoAPI
{
    private $driver;
    public function __construct($driver)
    {
        require_once "drivers/" . $driver . ".class.php";
        $driverClass = $driver . "_Driver";

        $this->driver = new $driverClass;
    }

    public function FetchVideoById($id)
    {
        return $this->driver->FetchVideoById($id);
    }
}
```

You would then have an interface for your drivers like so:

```
interface IVideoDriver
{
    public function FetchVideoById($id);
    /*.
        Other required methods
    .*/
}
```

and each driver would implement the method and extend the request class like so:

```
class Youtube_Driver extends VideoRequest implements IVideoDriver
{
    protected $base_url = "http://gdata.youtube.com"
    public function FetchVideoById($id)
    {
        $Request = $this->request($this->base_url . "/feeds/api/videos/",array(
            "format" => "json",
            "api_id" => $this->config->api_keys->youtube
        ));

        if($Request->status() == VideoRequest::STATUS_OK)
        {
             return $Request->Response();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert yes exactly all famous website provide api, but is there any fre php class exist that interact with all these websites ?

Comment: Updated with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

you should use curl o file_get_contents to retrieve the data you have linked to, then identify by mime-tipe (first).
If you got text/html mime tipe you should extract all images/objects from the page.

However the best way is to use curl to emulate a browser.
Maybe you can find some classes for that solution on http://phpclasses.org

Comment: Diego thanks for reply yes we can use curl and can find class phpclasses.org i did research but could't find any SOLID class if you know any can you please give me the url ?

Comment: There are a lot of classes found here: http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=HTTP&x=0&y=0&go_search=1 , the ones i consider most interesting are "Advanced HTTP Client" and "PHP HTTP protocol client".